# No member named idleMovie in ofVideoPlayer

Tags: c++, openframeworks

Any C++ gurus able to tell me why I get the following error

I've tried recreating the header file several times.

Is there possible something wrong with my header?

No member named idleMovie in ofVideoPlayer

```
void testApp::setup(){  

    // setup video dimensions  
    videoWidth = 320;  
    videoHeight = 240;  

    outputWidth = 320;  
    outputHeight = 240;  

    // masked image ofTexture  
    maskedImg.allocate(outputWidth,outputHeight,GL_RGBA);  

    // videograbber init  
    vidGrabber.setVerbose(true);  
    vidGrabber.initGrabber(videoWidth,videoHeight);  

    // background quicktime  
    vidPlayer.loadMovie("gracht5000.mov");  
    vidPlayer.play();  

    // video source  
    colorImg.allocate(outputWidth,outputHeight);  

    // grayscale source  
    grayImage.allocate(outputWidth,outputHeight);  
    // static difference image  
    grayBg.allocate(outputWidth,outputHeight);  
    // difference (mask) between grayscale source and static image  
    grayDiff.allocate(outputWidth,outputHeight);  

    bLearnBakground = true;  
    threshold = 80;  
}  

//--------------------------------------------------------------  
void testApp::update()  
{     
    ofBackground(100,100,100);  
    bool bNewFrame = false;  
    vidPlayer.idleMovie();  
    vidGrabber.grabFrame();  
    bNewFrame = vidGrabber.isFrameNew();  

    if (bNewFrame)  
    {  
        colorImg.setFromPixels(vidGrabber.getPixels(), outputWidth,outputHeight);  
        grayImage = colorImg;                 

        // learn new background image  
        if (bLearnBakground == true){  
            grayBg = grayImage; // the = sign copys the pixels from grayImage into grayBg (operator overloading)  
            bLearnBakground = false;  
        }  

        // take the abs value of the difference between background and incoming and then threshold:  
        grayDiff.absDiff(grayBg, grayImage);  
        grayDiff.threshold(threshold);  
        grayDiff.blur( 3 );  

        // pixels array of the mask  
        unsigned char * maskPixels = grayDiff.getPixels();    

        // pixel array of webcam video  
        unsigned char * colorPixels = colorImg.getPixels();  

        // numpixels in mask  
        int numPixels = outputWidth * outputHeight;  

        // masked video image (RGBA) (final result)  
        unsigned char * maskedPixels = new unsigned char[outputWidth*outputHeight*4];  

        // loop the mask  
        for(int i = 0; i < numPixels; i+=1 )  
        {  
            int basePixelRGBA = 4 * i;  
            int basePixelRGB = 3 * i;  

            // compose final result  
            maskedPixels[ basePixelRGBA + 0 ] = colorPixels[basePixelRGB]; // take pixels from webcam source  
            maskedPixels[ basePixelRGBA + 1 ] = colorPixels[basePixelRGB+1]; // take pixels from webcam source  
            maskedPixels[ basePixelRGBA + 2 ] = colorPixels[basePixelRGB+2]; // take pixels from webcam source  
            maskedPixels[ basePixelRGBA + 3 ] = maskPixels[i]; // alpha channel from mask pixel array  
        }  

        // load final image into texture  
        maskedImg.loadData(maskedPixels, outputWidth,outputHeight, GL_RGBA );  

    }  



}  

//--------------------------------------------------------------  
void testApp::draw(){  

    ofSetColor(0xffffff);  

    // draw bg video  
    vidPlayer.draw(0,0);  

    // draw masked webcam feed  
    ofEnableAlphaBlending();  
    maskedImg.draw(20,20);  
    ofDisableAlphaBlending();  

    // info  
    ofSetColor(0xffffff);  
    char reportStr[1024];  
    sprintf(reportStr, "bg subtraction and blob detection\npress ' ' to capture bg\nthreshold %i (press: +/-)\n, fps: %f", threshold, ofGetFrameRate());  
    ofDrawBitmapString(reportStr, 20, 600);  

}
```

HEADER

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofxOpenCv.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{

    public:
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();
        void keyPressed(int key);
        void keyReleased(int key);
        void mouseMoved(int x, int y );
        void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
        void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
        void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
        void windowResized(int w, int h);
        void dragEvent(ofDragInfo dragInfo);
        void gotMessage(ofMessage msg);
        int videoWidth;
        int videoHeight;
        int outputWidth;
        int outputHeight;
        int threshold;
        ofVideoGrabber vidGrabber;
        ofVideoPlayer vidPlayer;

        ofxCvColorImage colorImg;
        ofxCvGrayscaleImage grayImage;
        ofxCvGrayscaleImage grayBg;
        ofxCvGrayscaleImage grayDiff;
        ofTexture maskedImg;
        bool bLearnBakground;



 };
```

Comment: Your compiler is right, there is no member idleMovie: http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/video/ofVideoPlayer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vidPlayer.idleMovie();` replaced with `vidPlayer.update();`

and `vidGrabber.grabFrame();` got replaced by `vidGrabber.update();`